# ZMQ for dynamic peers in P2P application

Tags: c++, zeromq, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

I want to design a P2P application but without a dedicated peer (server) which can bind sockets. All the peers can join and leave anytime, it is a dynamic case. I tried to use ZMQ sockets with `REQ-REP pattern` for both `bind` and `connect` but at a time, a peer can act as either sender or receiver and it won't switch the role. Following code doesn't work and I need to have identical code for REQ-REP sockets/ peers.

```
  zmq::context_t context(1);
  zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);

  socket.bind("tcp://*:5555");
  // Wait for a message for some time and do work.


  zmq::context_t context2(1);
  zmq::socket_t socket2(context2, ZMQ_REQ);
  socket2.connect("tcp://localhost:6666");
  // Do work and send a message
```

Or is there something else that I can use for this type of design?

Comment: I think you must chose your server first, since ZMQ is not supporting this kind of connection. However, you could open 2 channels.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by channel? I don't see any such term in ZMQ guide. Is the `DEALER-ROUTER` pattern relevant to my use-case? Thanks.

Comment: By channel I mean the the connection in a more abstract manner. I.e. you could open one more `REQ-REP` channel in order to have clients which are also servers and vice versa.

Comment: In respect to your code, as far as I know, and maybe I'm wrong, you don't need to create a new `context` for every new socket, just create one `context` and pass it through sockets.